# Authlogic + Rails: Works local, but not on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, authlogic

I'm using Authlogic (3.4.6) in Rails 5 to handle authentication.

Instead of a `UserSession`, I've got:

```
class ClientInfoSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
end
```

I also have a `ClientInfo` model, which is like a `User` model:

```
class ClientInfo < ApplicationRecord


  validates :client_key, presence: true
  validates :client_id, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: [:client_key] }

  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.login_field = :client_id
    c.crypted_password_field = :client_key
    c.crypto_provider = nil
  end

end
```

Where `client_id` is a string (like a username) and `client_key` is like a password.

The following method is the action which attempts to create a session. It receives two parameters: `client_id` and `client_key`:

```
 def create
    client_info = ClientInfo.find_by(client_id: params[:client_id],
                                     client_key: params[:client_key])

    # Yes, I know I shouldn't keep passwords in the DB, but this
    # is not being used by anyone yet
    @client_info_session = ClientInfoSession.new(client_info)

    if @client_info_session.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Invalid user'
      render :new
    end
end
```

This works locally; the client is successfully authenticated. However, in a production environment, the authentication is not working correctly.

Whereas locally a cookies called `client_info_credentials` is created and has a reasonable value (a very long string), in production this cookie always has a value similar to `%3A%3A151` (it changes depending on the client id and key, but not by much). What's weird is that `@client_info_session.save` does return `true` because the redirection is happening instead of the `render`.

However, no user is detected by the server from the cookies on any subsequent request, so it's like no login happened.

Comment: How do the two environments' configurations differ? See the [rails config guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) for config options related to, e.g., cookies.